# Why do some vacancies list BSc, MSc, as well as a PhD as eligible education levels?

Tags: recruitment, job-description

E.g.,

> To succeed in this role, you should have the following skills and
> experience
>
> BSc / MSc or PhD Degree in Physics, Electrical Engineering, or
> Biomedical Engineering.

So which one do they actually need? Will a BSc require tons of training and will a PhD be overqualified? Or is a BSc probably enough, but they don't care and they'll hire overqualified people as well? Can anyone shed some light on why they are being so vague? I almost have my PhD in Physics and I don't know if I should bother applying for these jobs or skip 'em.

Comment: Some people do advanced degrees in fields completely different from what they did in undergrad. Sounds like this company just wants you have _A_ degree in one of those fields, they don't care what what degree it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do some vacancies list BSc, MSc, as well as a PhD as eligible education levels?

Likely because you can have a BSc, MSc, and PhD in three separate fields.

These companies want you to have at least one of your degrees ( if you have multiple ) in the required fields.

> I almost have my PhD in Physics and I don't know if I should bother applying for these jobs or skip 'em.

If it's a job you want and you feel you are qualified then you should apply, the worst that they can do is not accept your application.

Comment: +1 for the last part. Furthermore, even if you don't check ALL the boxes, if you check MOST of them, you should apply if you think the job is a good fit for you

Comment: That makes sense. In my country it's more habitual to have a BSc and MSc in the same subject because those educations often tightly mesh together. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone shed some light on why they are being so vague?

It's less vague and more *inclusive* - likely a BSc provides "sufficent" education for the position but if they just put "BSc" then they risk those with MSc and PhD degrees from ruling themselves out as "overqualified". More advanced degrees *may* be advantageous (it's by no means a given and there's no way to know without way more info on the job) but its not a dealbreaker and putting "MSc or PhD preferred" they risk excluding lots of talented people who "only" have a BSc from applying.

From the fact that they list some relatively diverse subjects what this requirement is saying IMO is "we want someone clever, with a STEM background and the sort of mindset and skills that brings" so..

> I almost have my PhD in Physics

sounds like you're probably all good.

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely a PhD will be directly relevant to the work, but it shows positive qualities and companies are normally keen to employ PhDs (for various reasons including boasting about the number of PhDs they have).

Comment: I saw this happen to two people I know at a local pharmaceutical firm.  One had a BS and one had a ABD in chemistry.  They did the same job (possibly one was a replacement for the other), and one told me that in that field, a chemist with a Ph.D. but without the right post doc was considered to be basically the same as a BS.